# Passing value from one callback to another callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created the following plugin that mostly works.  It takes xeditable, but allows for jQueryUI's autocomplete to select the value.  It mostly works, however, I am struggling on how to pass the returned `id` from jQueryUI Autocomplete to the success callback.

How do I pass a value from the jQueryUI autocomplete select callback to the xeditable success callback?

EDIT.  I got it working, but think it is a bit of a kludge.  What is the proper way to do so?

EDIT #2.  See https://jsfiddle.net/fndnu5m0/5/ for a demo.

```
$('#targetID').xeditableAutoSource({
    source: 'getSource.php',
    success: function(response, newValue) {
        console.log($(this).data('uid')); //This is the value I want!
    }
});

(function($){

    var defaults = {
        source: [],     //Replace with URL
        placement: 'right',
        title: 'XEditable Title',
        success: function(response, newValue) {}    //id will be $(this).data('uid')
    };

    var methods = {
        init : function (options) {
            var settings = $.extend({},defaults, options  || {});

            this.each(function () {

                var $this=$(this).editable({
                    //send:'never',
                    placement:settings.placement,
                    title:settings.title,
                    success: settings.success
                })
                .on('shown', function(e, editable) {
                    var $input=editable.input.$input.val('');
                    var $button=$input.parent().next().find('button.editable-submit').css('opacity', 0.3)
                    .bind('click.prevent', function() {return false;});
                    $input.focus(function() {
                        $button.css('opacity', 0.3).bind('click.prevent', function() {return false;});
                    })
                    .autocomplete({
                        source: settings.source,
                        select: function(e, ui) {
                            $input.blur();
                            $button.css('opacity', 1).unbind('click.prevent');
                            $this.data('uid',ui.item.id);  //This is the value I need in the success callback!
                        }
                    })
                    .autocomplete('widget').click(function() {return false;});
                });

            })
        },
        destroy : function () {
            return this.each(function () {
                return this.each(function () {});
            });
        }
    };

    $.fn.xeditableAutoSource = function(method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || ! method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.xeditableAutoSource');
        }    
    };
    }(jQuery));
```

Comment: Create a demo so we can walk through this

Comment: @charlietfl  Give me a minute.  Thanks.  PS.  You like jsbin, jsfiddle, or something else?

Comment: fiddle sounds good. Easy to add jQuery UI and would just need CDN paths for xEditable

Comment: @charlietfl  Sorry, took a little longer than expected.  xeditable doesn't seem to work with current versions of jqueryui.  Please see https://jsfiddle.net/31jm8v9g/.  The source is just an array which starts with an `a` or `b`.  Thank you.

Comment: seems to work for me

Comment: @charlietfl  You mean my demo works?  Because I am using an old version of jQueryUI.  Yes, I am able to pass the value.  But is this really the "right" way to do it.  While it works for me, I would like to better understand how it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Too much code... As far as I understood you want to pass to a function not just a callback but also its parameter. You can try the following technique:

```
var f1 = function(callback) {      //we will pass a callback to this function
  callback()
}
var f2= function(param1) {         //that will be our callback
  console.log(param1) 
}

var p = 'Callback will always be called with this parameter'
f1(  function() { f2(p) }  )       //here we pass f2 with p as a callback to f1
```

Callback and it's parameter are wrapped into anonymous function. 'f1' and 'f2' are the functions from you libraries, you don't have to modify them, they are needed to illustrate the technique.

With some minor changes you can make it work if a function that accepts a callback passes some other parameters to it:

```
var f1 = function(callback) {
  var p1 = 'Parameter set by f1'
  callback(p1)
}
var f2= function(param1, param2) {
  console.log(param1 +' '+ param2) 
}

var p = 'Constant parameter'
f1(  function(p1) { f2(p1, p) }  )
```

Comment: Without modifying the stock jqueryui autocomplete script and the xeditable script, can this be done with my example?  Note that I have since added a fiddle.  I only wish to modify my plugin script.

Comment: @user1032531 Imagine that `f1` and `f2` functions are the ones from your libraries. You don't have to modify them all you need is wrap a callback with anonymous function when you pass it `f1(  function(p1) { f2(p1, p) }  )`.